# Why Typescript Code is (or is not) a Circular Dependency?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

The below code confused me, cause i think it may be a circular dependency, but Typescript allows the below code. Can anyone explain what this code actually does?

```
interface A extends Array<B> { };
type B = A;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript allows recursive definition, it even allows `interface A extends Array<A> { };`

I don't know where this specific definition would be useful but here is an example of why it was introduced in TypeScript.

Original Source:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050

```
type ValueOrArray<T> = T | Array<ValueOrArray<T>>;

const a0: ValueOrArray<number> = 1;
const a1: ValueOrArray<number> = [1, [2, 3], [4, [5, [6, 7]]]];

type HypertextNode = string | [string, { [key: string]: any }, ...HypertextNode[]];

const hypertextNode: HypertextNode =
    ["div", { id: "parent" },
        ["div", { id: "first-child" }, "I'm the first child"],
        ["div", { id: "second-child" }, "I'm the second child"]
    ];

type Json = string | number | boolean | null | Json[] | { [key: string]: Json };

let data: Json = {
  caption: "Test",
  location: { x: 10, y: 20 },
  values: [0, 10, 20]
}
```

JavaScript allows object to take shape of any type of object, and TypeScript tries to allow type checking around most used cases. The above example is perfect case of this pattern where recursive type definition makes sense.

Since Types remain only within TypeScript compilation context, they are are not circular dependency as in runtime all types vanish and all left is pure JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you, the example you provided makes sense. Actually I found the issue from React's `index.d.ts` where it defines ReactNode.